# VBA Macro (Excel 2010): Runtime Error 5

Tags: vba, excel

I've made a small macro to remove several unwanted characters in a long list of reports. I wanted to remove the HTML tags from a string and ran into an unexpected runtime error.

I've been having this weird runtime error on:

```
strMatter = Mid(str2010, 1, Len(str2010) - 10)
```

Whereas something similar does work:

```
b = Mid(a, 1, Len(a) - 10)
```

The difference is that the line above is run in a "For To Loop". Logically I've tried several things to work around the issue and it seems that I'm not allowed to decrease a variable whilst in the loop. How can I work around this?

The B column before any macro's are run: [strPlaceholder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyvjY.png)

The B column after the macro has run: [str2010](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mr7T1.png)

Every help and/or suggestions are more than welcome!

> Edit:
>
> I've changed `For intRow = 2 To 5000`
>
> To `For intRow = 2 To 13`
>
> And everything works. How do I alter the script in such a way that it finds the last row?

Here's the entire little code:

```
    Sub WHYYYY()

Dim strPlaceholder As String
Dim strPhrase As String
Dim str2010 As String
Dim strMatter As String
Dim strStart As String
Dim strEnd As String
Dim intRow As Integer
Dim intChar As Integer
Dim intLen As Integer

For intRow = 2 To 5000

    'Clean Description Column
    strPlaceholder = Cells(intRow, 2).Value
    If Not Trim(Len(strPlaceholder)) = 0 Then
        strPhrase = strPlaceholder
        str2010 = Mid(strPhrase, 63, Len(strPhrase))
        strMatter = Mid(str2010, 1, Len(str2010) - 10)
        Cells(intRow, 2) = str2010  'Should be = strMatter
    End If

    'Clean Legal Responsible Column
    strStart = Cells(intRow, 7).Value
    intLen = Len(strStart)

    For intChar = 1 To intLen
        If Not IsNumeric(Mid(strStart, intChar, 1)) Then
            strEnd = strEnd & Mid(strStart, intChar, 1)
        End If
        Cells(intRow, 7) = strEnd
    Next

    Cells(intRow, 7) = Mid(strEnd, 3, 50)
    strEnd = ""

    'Clean Business Responsible Column
    strStart = Cells(intRow, 8).Value
    intLen = Len(strStart)

    For intChar = 1 To intLen
        If Not IsNumeric(Mid(strStart, intChar, 1)) Then
            strEnd = strEnd & Mid(strStart, intChar, 1)
        End If
        Cells(intRow, 8) = strEnd
    Next

    Cells(intRow, 8) = Mid(strEnd, 3, 50)
    strEnd = ""

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You have blanks in column b

Comment: `str2010` in your example is a substring starting at position `63` - I imagine there's not much text in that variable for you to perform another `Mid()` function on... Also what is the value of `intChar` at the time of the error?

Comment: It doesn't look like `strPhrase` has 63 characters.

Comment: Or that str2010 has less than 10 characters

Comment: Recommend you check to see if `IsNull(...)` is really doing what you expect.  If you are checking for an empty cell, that is not the same.  Better to check something like `Len(...) = 0`  (or even `Trim(Len(...))=0`)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - If Not Trim(Len(strPlaceholder)) = 0 Then .... throwes the same error at the same line. But thanks, it does allow for better errorcatching!

Comment: @Ramon When I run your code with your posted data, it does NOT return an error.  However, it also does not properly clean the data.  Oh, and do you want the HTML tags after the retained line to be retained?  As you show in your screenshot?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - user3598756's answer neatly solves the issue. But for some reason, both the Null and Len checks both failed, as after the 13th row, where I had no test data, the code would throw the error. The code I've got now looks entirely different and it works without flaws :) Still thanks to everybody willing to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't understand whether the issue at this time is still the one in the question, which still reads:

---

*I've been having this weird runtime error on:*

```
strMatter = Mid(str2010, 1, Len(str2010) - 10)
```

*Whereas something similar does work:*

```
b = Mid(a, 1, Len(a) - 10)
```

---

should it still be then you could change "strategy" like follows

```
Dim cell As Range

With Worksheets("MySheet") '<~~ replace "MySheet" with your actual sheet name
    With Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
        .Replace What:="*><p>", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
        .Replace What:="</p></div>*", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False

        For Each cell In .Cells
            ' do other stuff
        Next cell

    End With
End With
```

Comment: Perfect! That change in "strategy" was exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. Thanks a bunch!